# Self-hosted SignalR2 multi-layer dependency injection

Tags: c#, dll, console-application, ninject, signalr-2

I've just implemented DI using Ninject for my self-hosted SignalR2 project.

```
public class NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    public NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType).Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }
}
```

And my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(kernel);

        kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf();

        kernel.Bind<IRealTimeDataEngine>().To<RealTimeDataEngine>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IHistoricalDataEngine>().To<HistoricalDataEngine>().InSingletonScope();

        kernel.Bind(typeof(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic>)).ToMethod(context =>
            resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients
        ).WhenInjectedInto<IRealTimeDataEngine>();

        var config = new HubConfiguration {Resolver = resolver};
        ConfigureSignalR(app, config);
    }

    public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app, HubConfiguration config)
    {
        app.MapSignalR(config);
    }
}
```

In my signalr hub constructor I expect an IRealTimeDataEngine.

```
public MyHub(IRealTimeDataEngine realTimeDataEngine, IHistoricalDataEngine historicalDataEngine)
```

In my host, which is a console application, I need the same IRealTimeDataEngine to be injected.

```
public DummyProvider(IRealTimeDataEngine realTimeDataEngine)
```

In my Main method I need to create a DummyProvider object.

If I'm not mistaken, creating a new kernel would not give me the same object in the two different projects, so how should I ask for the same IRealTimeDataEngine at my composition root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right you must use only one kernel per application. That means you should create your kernel outside of `Startup` class in your case. This can be achieved by using overloaded call of `WebApp.Start` method like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var kernel = new StandardKernel();

       var server = WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080/", (appBuilder) =>
       {
           var resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(kernel);
           var config = new HubConfiguration {Resolver = resolver};
           ...
       });

       ...
```